# UPDATE Identity Values in Non Unique Column in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

Here, I'm facing a major issues in Teradata. which is I can't UPDATE an Identity Values like(1,2,3,4,. . . ) in to COLUMN, that particular table doesn't have any (PRIMARY KEY or PRIMARY INDEX or UNIQUE INDEX) COLUMN.

In this case, How can I add an IDENTITY VALUES into NON_UNIQUE column for the table?

For Example:

```
Create table test(emp_id integer, emp_name varchar(20));

Insert into test(2015,'XYZ');
Insert into test(2016,'XYZ');
Insert into test(2015,'ABC');
Insert into test(2016,'ABC');
```

In the above example, both columns are NON_UNIQUE, now I want to achieve any one the below case:

1. How to UPDATE EMP_ID column to IDENTITY VALUES like (1,2,3,...)
2. Or else, How to ADD IDENTITY COLUMN VALUES into same table?

Comment: In your actaul data are there duplicate rows, i.e. exactly the same data more than once? And simply adding an IDENTITY will not clean your data.

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, I'm having duplicates rows also in my tables. But, In my case simply I want to add an IDENTITY column like (1,2,3) in to same tables.

Comment: When you got duplicate rows you can only create a new table. Either do an insert/select where you calculate a ROW_NUMBER or add an IDENTITY column to the new table (but the values will not be sequential). How big is your actual table?

Comment: But, Teradata does not provide  ADD an IDENTITY COLUMN into EXISTING table !!

Comment: Correct. Again: You must create a new table.